# Request for references: Best way to estimate directed graphs *with* cycles

Tags: references, lasso, graphical-model, bayesian-network, networks

I have $n$ observations of $p$ random variables $\{Y_1,\dots,Y_p \}$. I know that each observation has been generated from a linear network model of the form
$$
Y = WY+\epsilon
$$
and that the graph described by $W$ is likely to be sparse and to have cycles. What is the current state of the art for estimating $W$? I have been reading about the graphical lasso but it seems limited to undirected graphs or acyclic directed graphs.

Comment: Are $Y$ on the left hand side and $Y$ on the right hand side the same? Could you clarify what $Y$, $W$ and $\epsilon$ are?

Comment: Yes the $Y$ on the left and right hand side are the same. $W$ is a $p\times p$ matrix and $\epsilon$ is a vector of iid normal variable.

Comment: So does this mean $Y_k = (I-W)^{-1}\epsilon_k$ or am I misunderstanding the setting completely?

Comment: Exactly (if $k$ is a vector of observations)! The issue is now to estimate $W$.

Comment: Um, $k$ is an index(ing integer), $Y_k$ is a $p$-dimensional vector.

Comment: Yep, sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: Can you say more about the direct cyclic idea, and how you see the relationship between the graph and the matrix $W$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by direct cycle, but a cycle is a path from a node that ends at the same node by following only directed connection in the network. I want to authorize such cycle in $W$. The matrix $W$ is essentially such that $W_{ij}=1$ if there is a ling from $i$ to $j$.